# Serializing C# class and returning JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, json

```
    string query = context.Request.QueryString["tag"];
    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer JsonSerializer =
        new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    context.Response.Write(JsonSerializer.Serialize(Category.GetAll()));
```

This returns successfully but how can I name the returned JSON array?
Like by default ASP.NET names json arrays returned with "d". How can I create the same functionality when doing my own returns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want something named "d", maybe:

```
var obj = new { d = Category.GetAll() };
```

And serialize that:

```
context.Response.Write(JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj));
```